# UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS 10 dropbox location seen for a second and disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController in import mode. On iOS 11 everything working fine. In iOS 10 in document view when I press Locations -> More: dropbox is shown for a second and disappears. Looks like it works correctly in iOS mail...

Code snippet:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue ? I am facing it right now :( .

Comment: Setting the UINavigationBar isTranslucent property to true fixes the issue.